# Deploy multiple projects into single app service

Tags: web-applications, azure-devops, microservices, azure-web-app-service

> I want to deploy two projects into azure DevOps CI/CD. I created a pipeline
> which points to one app service which I created in Azure portal and
> deploy it. I am able to deploy one web project at a time, however when
> I try to add one more project (microservice) then release fail.

I am getting following error.
[image]

please suggest something on this.

> I want to use same app service and deploy one web application and microservice.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding two separate 'Deploy Azure App Service' steps to the release pipeline.

Make sure you change the package field

[image]

from: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip

to: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/****/[website-name].zip

and to: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/****/[microservice-name].zip

As far as i know you can't deploy it to a single app service, as this is designed to run a single web app. the approach above can be used to deploy it to a single app service plan, but will create separate app services in the same plan.
This will not have any cost implication as you are paying for the plan not the sites, but will run them as separate websites (do note that as they are on the same plan they will be using the same resources so if one gets a lot of load the other could also suffer from that)

Comment: is it possible to do it without creating two app services. I want to deploy it to one app service

Comment: As far as i know you cant deploy it to a single app service, as this is designed to run a single web app. the approach above can be used to deploy it to a single app service plan, but will create separate app services in the same plan.

This will not have any cost implication as you are paying for the plan not the sites, but will run them as separate websites (do note that as they are on the same plan they will be using the same resources so if one gets a lot of load the other could also suffer from that)

Comment: @RemcoBrilstra you should publish that comment as a separate Answer. That's the real solution.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Added it to the original answer, should provide a more complete answer that way

Comment: I really think it would be better as a separate answer; it's two quite different issues being discussed.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are trying to do is better solved in the Release part of DevOps.

1. Create separate builds for both projects (this is still in Build stage)
2. Create one release, and add both projects's artifacts (Image 1)
3. You can sequence the deployment of each project when you create the stages - lets say  prod stage.
4. You can alternatively create one stage with separate tasks for the deployment of each solution. (Image 2)

[image: Iamge 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of trying to make a single Azure App Service run two different services (which it won't do)